# Unable to export Bookmarks to newer version of Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, backup

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The problem is I cannot successfully export firefox bookmarks in old Ubuntu (18.04)to new (20.04). I performed the following actions:

1. Went into old ubuntu (18.04)
2. Called up bookmarks "library" in firefox
3. Clicked "import and backup" tag
4. Clicked "Export bookmarks to html..."
5. Saved html file
6. Rebooted to ubuntu 20.04
7. Called up bookmarks "library" in firefox
8. Clicked "import and backup" tag
9. Clicked "Import bookmarks from html..."
10. Opened previously saved html file (see step 5))
11. Nothing happened!

Comment: If you are using the same versions of Firefox.  Check the info under the Help/About menu. All you need to do is copy the profile folder from one install to the next.  It will all be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have just gone into firefox again and my old bookmarks have saved successfully! I have no idea how they have suddenly appeared. Must have previously clicked on the wrong tab on the left side of the library or something. Anyway, it worked so all good.